# Simple Count Mysql query

Tags: mysql, count

```
receipt_id           order_id
1                       A
2                       B
3                       B
4                       C
5                       C
```

What is the sql code to show all the records in this table where order_id's count is more than 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Select * from table where order_id in (select  distinct order_id
 from table
 group by order_id
 having count(order_id) > 1)
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96d2e/4/0)**

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although it takes a lot of time to execute in a large table.

Comment: just create an index on order_id

Answer (score 3):

You just need an aggregate function with a `GROUP BY`

```
select order_id
from yourtable
group by order_id
having count(order_id) > 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8887e/1)